# rxjs merge: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am getting an error `You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected.` when I try to merge observbles.

i create my refresh observable here:

```
refresh$: Observable<Funnel[]>;
```

then I have a timer...

```
TimerObservable.create(0, (this.storageService.refRate * 1000))
    .takeWhile(() => this.interval)
    .subscribe(() => {
        this.refresh$ = this.funnelService.getStoryFunnels({}).map(response => [...response]);
    });
```

and then when I try to merge the observable, the error is produced:

```
this.funnels$ = this.funnelService.getStoryFunnels({}).pipe(
    merge(this.refresh$, funnelCreation$.pipe(
            filter(funnel => !!funnel),
            map(funnel => [funnel])
        )
    )
);
```

update based on cozy's answer:

```
this.refresh$ = TimerObservable.create(0, (this.storageService.refRate * 500))
    .takeWhile(() => this.interval)
    .switchMap(() =>  this.funnelService.getStoryFunnels({}).map(response => [...response]));
```

and then:

```
this.funnels$ = this.funnelService.getStoryFunnels({}).pipe(
        merge(this.refresh$, funnelCreation$.pipe(
                filter(funnel => !!funnel),
                map(funnel => [funnel])
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: Just realized you `refresh$` and `funnel$` are both depending on `this.funnelService.getStorryFunnels()`. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @CozyAzure we are trying to update the display every two minutes. so this.funnels is the async that gets passed to the template, and refresh is just to update it.

Comment: then you do not need to merge at all. Just pass `this.refresh$` to your template and it should be working as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `this.funnels$` **isn't an observable yet** when it was declared (not initiated with any values), because it will only be assigned a value only after the timer is executed. The declaration code however, is executed almost immediately (synchronous). That is why you get an `undefined`.

What you should do is you can use `switchMap` and assign your `this.refresh$` to it:

```
this.refresh$ = TimerObservable.create(0, (this.storageService.refRate * 1000))
    .takeWhile(() => this.interval)
    .switchMap(() =>  this.funnelService.getStoryFunnels({}).map(response => [...response]));
```

Comment: this got rid of the error, but I don't seem to see the result, i should see it mat the api call in network inspector. I will updat emy code above...